# How can I update an amp-web-push widget on subscribe?

Tags: amp-html, web-push

I'm trying to implement the amp-web-push component in my page. I use a personnal subscription code and it work fine. My problem is the widget use visibility="unsubscribed" to display a subscribe button, and this visibility is not updated when I subscribe myself to notifications. My other problem is that the button is still displayed if I refuse notification.
See my code below:

**amp.html**

```html
<html ⚡ lang="en" tabindex="0" data-ampdevmode>
  <head>
    ..
  </head>

  <body style="height:20em !important;" >
   
    <amp-web-push-widget visibility="unsubscribed" layout="fixed" width="245" height="45">
    <button class="subscribe" on="tap:amp-web-push.subscribe">
      <amp-img
              class="subscribe-icon"
              width="24"
              height="24"
              layout="fixed"
              src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBjbGFzcz0ic3Vic2NyaWJlLWljb24iIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xMS44NCAxOS44ODdIMS4yMnMtLjk0Ny0uMDk0LS45NDctLjk5NWMwLS45LjgwNi0uOTQ4LjgwNi0uOTQ4czMuMTctMS41MTcgMy4xNy0yLjYwOGMwLTEuMDktLjUyLTEuODUtLjUyLTYuMzA1czIuODUtNy44NyA2LjI2LTcuODdjMCAwIC40NzMtMS4xMzQgMS44NS0xLjEzNCAxLjMyNSAwIDEuOCAxLjEzNyAxLjggMS4xMzcgMy40MTMgMCA2LjI2IDMuNDE4IDYuMjYgNy44NyAwIDQuNDYtLjQ3NyA1LjIyLS40NzcgNi4zMSAwIDEuMDkgMy4xNzYgMi42MDcgMy4xNzYgMi42MDdzLjgxLjA0Ni44MS45NDdjMCAuODUzLS45OTYuOTk1LS45OTYuOTk1SDExLjg0ek04IDIwLjk3N2g3LjExcy0uNDkgMi45ODctMy41MyAyLjk4N1M4IDIwLjk3OCA4IDIwLjk3OHoiIGZpbGw9IiNGRkYiLz48L3N2Zz4=">
      </amp-img>
      Subscribe to notifications
    </button>

</amp-web-push-widget>
  <amp-web-push
    id="amp-web-push"
    layout="nodisplay"
    helper-iframe-url="https://..."
    permission-dialog-url="https://..."
    service-worker-url="https://..."
  ></amp-web-push>
  </body>
</html>
```

**serviceworker.js**

````js
...
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data.command == WorkerMessengerCommand.AMP_SUBSCRIPTION_STATE) {
    onMessageReceivedSubscriptionState();
  } else if (event.data.command == WorkerMessengerCommand.AMP_SUBSCRIBE) {
    onMessageReceivedSubscribe();
  } else if (event.data.command == WorkerMessengerCommand.AMP_UNSUBSCRIBE) {
    onMessageReceivedUnsubscribe();
  } 
}


function onMessageReceivedSubscriptionState() {
  let retrievedPushSubscription = null;
  self.registration.pushManager
    .getSubscription()
    .then((pushSubscription) => {
      retrievedPushSubscription = pushSubscription;
      if (!pushSubscription) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return self.registration.pushManager.permissionState(
          pushSubscription.options
        );
      }
    })
    .then((permissionStateOrNull) => {
      console.log(permissionStateOrNull);
      if (permissionStateOrNull == null) {
        broadcastReply(WorkerMessengerCommand.AMP_SUBSCRIPTION_STATE, false);
      } else {
        const isSubscribed =
          !!retrievedPushSubscription && permissionStateOrNull === 'granted';
        broadcastReply(
          WorkerMessengerCommand.AMP_SUBSCRIPTION_STATE,
          isSubscribed
        );
      }
    });
}


function onMessageReceivedSubscribe() {
  broadcastReply(WorkerMessengerCommand.AMP_SUBSCRIBE, null);
}
...```
````